# Best practice for making third-party class parcelable?

Tags: android, parcelable, urbanairship.com

I am using a push notification third-party solution (specifically `RichPushMessage` class from Urban Airship push notification lib). I have created a bundle to be passed about that contains a `RichPushMessage` field. I need it to implement `Parcelable`. I cannot subclass `RichPushMessage` as its constructor is private. How best to go about making this class parcelable?

Answer (score 2):

Even if you could subclass it, you would not be able to create a RichPushMessage as that is handled by the Urban Airship SDK.

I am not sure if its possible to do what you are asking, but here are a few alternatives:

1) Store the message ID in the bundle:

```
// Put it into the bundle
Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
bundle.putString(MESSAGE_ID_KEY, message.getMessageId());

// Pull it out of the bundle
String messageId = bundle.getString(MESSAGE_ID_KEY);
RichPushMessage message = UAirship.shared().getInbox().getMessage(messageId);
```

2) Create a class that wraps a RichPushMessage that you can make parcelable